# Cube Js | How to join two tables for measures and dimensions

Tags: cube, cube.js

I want to Join two tables which is User and Organizations. I don't know how to connect another table which is Organizations where i have to write query for that.

```
*cube(`Users`, {
  sql: `select * from users`,
  joins: {
    Organizations: {
      relationship: `belongsTo`,
      sql: `${Users}.organization_id = ${Organizations}.id`
   }
  },
  }
});*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create another schema for your another table name like below

```
cube(`Organizations`, {
   sql: `select * from organizations`,
   measures:{
      count: {
         type: `count`,
         drillMembers: [id]
      }
   },
});
```

You just simply creating a new schema and write the joins whatever columns you want. After that use can easily access in both dimensions and measures.